# What is the smallest number N that has 3 ways of split its square to get the sum divided parts is N?

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, computer-science

What is the smallest number N that has 3 at least ways of split its square to get the sum of divided parts is N? Example:

```
    9 = sqrt(81) = 8+1; 
    82 = sqrt(6724) = 6 + 72 + 4
```

with 91 we have 2 ways:

```
    91 = sqrt (8281) = 82+8+1 = 8+2+81
```

Comment: At *least* 3 ways, or *exactly* 3 ways? For at least, try `999` (which has 4 ways). For exactly, `5050`. But did you just want the answer, or do you have a question about how to write an algorithm to get to an answer?

Comment: @MarkDickinson My question is to find the _smallest number_ have _at least_ 3 ways. I am trying to find an algorithm here.

Comment: Thanks, those details are probably worth editing into the question. And is it legitimate to consider `998 + 001`, `998 + 00 + 1`, `998 + 0 + 01` and `998 + 0 + 0 + 1` as distinct ways? If not, what are the rules?

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question. But 999 has only 1 way.

Comment: Then you need to clarify the rules. 999^2 is 998001, and I see `998 | 001`, `998 | 0 | 01`, `998 | 00 | 1` and `998 | 0 | 0 | 1` as four distinct splits.

Comment: I did not think of that detail, but I am considering they are the same.

Comment: "I am considering they are the same" <- that's fine, but please clarify what rules you're applying to decide whether two splits are the same or not. Is it just about throwing out zeros? Or for example would `99|999` and `999|99` count as the same split of `99999`? (Yes, I know `99999` is not a square.)

Comment: Thanks, can you share your algorithm? I'm finding one without trying every case with every number.

Comment: I agree with @MarkDickinson.  I can easily solve multiple variations of this problem, but I don't know what the actual problem you want solved is.